# Javascript extractor problem with CodeQL create database

Tags: codeql

I issued the command:

codeql database create ./databases/Pixi --language="javascript" --source-root="Pixi"

And got the following errors:

Initializing database at /sda8/codeql-2.11.1/program/databases/Pixi.
A fatal error occurred: There's no CodeQL extractor named 'javascript' installed.

codeql version is 2.11.1.

Comment: What is the output when you run `codeql resolve languages`? Does your CodeQL CLI installation have a `codeql/javascript` folder? Have you tried reinstalling / downloading CodeQL CLI again (in case it got corrupted somehow)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error "no CodeQL extractor" found is because "codeql" as found in the $PATH was symbolically linked to the actual codeql.

For example, actual codeql was located at /sda8/codeql-2.11.1/codeql, but:

PATH=$HOME/codeql:$PATH

and

$HOME/codeql -> /sda8/codeql-2.11.1/codeql

the codeql as accessed in the $PATH was $HOME/codeql, symbolically linked to /sda8/codeql-2.11.1/codeql.

This will consistently give rise to the same error - over many different version of CodeQL.